# Create multiple items from checkbox input of single new item?

Tags: 2007, list

In custom list,  I have multiple entries with similar data, except one field.

When I create a new Item, I have to create new entry with the same data except one for each input.

I'll take one simple example. I have entries like these

```
Europe       English        Sp2007 
Europe       Spanish        Sp2007  
Europe       German         Sp2007
Europe       Italian        Sp2007
Europe       French         Sp2007
Europe       Portuguese     Sp2007
```

As of now, I have to create multiple newt for inputting this information. I know about datasheet view but that is not the point.

Is it possible to have multiple input entries based on number of checkboxes I select.

Lets say, for new entry(Continent), I input Europe. 
In checkboxes I select all above languages and click ok.
It should be able to create six new entries with different languages.

If I select Spanish and Portuguese only(from checkboxes), then it should create only two items with two lang.

```
South America     Spanish     Sp2007
South America     Portuguese  SP2007
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this out of the box.

My solution would be to create a webpart that has input fields for your columns and a collection of checkboxes and then creates the items.